# Infinite Series $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m^m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

*Any ideas to calculate this infinite sum?*
The ratio test guarantees the convergence;
$$\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{m^m}{(m+1)^{(m+1)}}=0<1$$

Comment: I faced this series while I was trying to evaluate an integral using Taylor expansion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: @MarcoCantarini That was probably the integral he was trying to evaluate. But it doesn't seem like you can find any simpler expression.

Comment: Thanks! actually I was trying to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} x^x dx$. By using Taylor expansion I faced the above series.

Comment: @Mehran- this is the second integral on the Wikipedia page, no? =0.7834...